# Best way to fix couldn't match expected type when your giving the right type (probably not)

Tags: haskell

Sorry for asking another question about this dice game :).

I've got the following code:

```
--type GepakteStenen = [Steen]
--data Tactiek = Tactiek
--  {tactiekPakken    ::GepakteStenen -> Worp -> IO Steen
--, tactiekDoorgaan   ::GepakteStenen -> IO Bool
-- }
tactiekUitv :: Worp -> GepakteStenen -> Predicaat -> IO(Steen,Bool)
tactiekUitv w g p = do s <- (tactiekPakken g w)
                       let gs = g ++ filter (s==) w
                       if (magStoppen p gs) then 
                         return (s,tactiekDoorgaan gs)
                       else
                         return (s,True)
```

Where i get this error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Tactiek' with actual type `[Steen]'
```

Why is it that i am giving the right type to my "tactiekDoorgaan" function, it wants me to create that a Tactiek of that?

Answer (score 1):

This declaration

```
data Tactiek = Tactiek
  { tactiekPakken :: GepakteStenen -> Worp -> IO Steen
  ...
```

makes `tactiekPakken` a *three* argument function

```
tactiekPakken :: Tactiek -> GepakteStenen -> Worp -> IO Steen
              -- ^^^^^^^ --
```

because there is a first, implicit argument having your record type. this might be confusing at first, but after all, we can not access a record field without having a record value at hand.

In your code, you do not provide the implicit `Tactiek` argument

```
do s <- (tactiekPakken g w)
     -- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ --
```

Comment: Thanks for the help im still not really sure if i get it now :). But will try to fix it. My guess is i need to add a "Tactiek" here: tactiekUitv :: Worp -> GepakteStenen -> Predicaat -> IO(Steen,Bool). Then i need to use that Tactiek like this: tactiekPakken t g w?

Comment: @SapereAude86 I guess so, I don't know what you are trying to do in your code. To call `tactiekPakken` you need to have some `Tactiek` value around. Probably you need that as an additional argument `t` in your `tactiekUitv` as you suggest.